# How to swap values from one generic list to another

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have 2 T Lists e.g:
list1 with attributes {ID, Name, Email}
list2 is of the same type
What I want is to be able to replace list1 ID values with ID values from list2, not affecting any Name and Email values
Eventually I would be even happier if I could have List list2 values to replace ID values from list1.
Thanks a lot.

I have tryed using for loop but it does not seem to work:

```
`for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
            {
                list1[i].GroupID =list2[i].GroupID;
            }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
   var temp = list1[i].GroupID;
   // swap
   list1[i].GroupID = list2[i].GroupID;
   list2[i].GroupID = temp;
}
```

Or Use tuple.

```
for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
   // swap
   (list1[i].GroupID, list2[i].GroupID) = (list2[i].GroupID, list1[i].GroupID)
}
```

Both methods must have the same count of list1 and list2.